# BATCH Script - pipe something into a file in a non existing folder

Tags: batch-file, pipe

Are there any possibilities to pipe something in a non-existing folder, like

```
"bla bla" > .\nonexisitngFolder\bla.txt
```

The above gives this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Or does it only work like

```
mkdir .\nonexisitngFolder
"bla bla" > .\nonexisitngFolder\bla.txt
```

Comment: Command `mkdir` can create a folder tree (create several folders at once). But the file creation routines in Windows kernel require that the folders already exist for the file. Therefore it would be best to use `if not exist "Folder\Tree\For File\" mkdir "Folder\Tree\For File\"` to create all folders for the file if at least on in folder tree is missing.

Comment: The DOS/cmd.exe shell does not have the feature of creating a directory automatically when the directory of a target new file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with Mofi's solution.

```
if not exist nonexistingFolder mkdir nonexistingFolder
"bla bla" > .\nonexistingFolder\bla.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure that the directory must exist if you’re outputting a file to it. 
Could you give more background on what your trying to do ?

Comment: I call a makefile from ruby _IO.popen(commandString, "r+")_ and want to pipe the output always in the same file in the same directory. The folder can exists but not necessarily.